# c++ Expression: string subscript out of range error

Tags: c++

hello i am new to programming but every time i run this code i get the error "c++ Expression: string subscript out of range" i am pretty sure that the error is in the second for loop

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string x;
string n;
cin >> x;


for (int i = 0; i <= x.length(); i++){
    if (x[i] == 'a' || x[i] == 'e' || x[i] == 'i' || x[i] == 'o' || x[i] == 'u' || x[i] == 'y')
    {
        x[i] = ' ';

    }


}
x.erase(remove_if(x.begin(), x.end(), isspace), x.end());
int f = x.length() * 2;
for (int i = 0; i <f-1; i+=2){

    n[i] = '.';

}
cout << n << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x.length(); i++)
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
```

because index starts from `0`

Comment: make sure:`for (int i = 0; i <f-1; i+=2){` does not access out of bound

Answer (score 2):

1. `x[x.length()]` out of range
2. can not use `n[index]` when the size of n is 0,use `n.push_back()`

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){  //error
           if (x[i] == 'a' || x[i] == 'e' || x[i] == 'i' || x[i] == 'o' || x[i] == 'u' || x[i] == 'y')
           {
               x[i] = ' ';

       }


       }
       x.erase(remove_if(x.begin(), x.end(), isspace), x.end());
       int f = x.length() * 2;
       for (int i = 0; i <f-1; i+=2){

           n[i] = '.';  // n.push_back('.');

       }
       cout << n <
   ```

   < endl;

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove all the vowels from your input string, you do not need to run two separate loops. You are already using std::remove_if, just add lambda shown in following code and you will have your desired output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string str = "This is test of vowels aeiou to be removed. Also the upper case AEIOU.";

    std::cout << "Original String: " << str << std::endl;

    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char x) {
        return (x == 'a'|| x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u' || x == 'y'
                || x == 'A'|| x == 'E' || x == 'I' || x == 'O' || x == 'U' || x == 'Y')

    }), str.end());
    std::cout << "String with vowels removed: " << str << std::endl;

    // Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this code.
    int f = x.length() * 2;
    for (int i = 0; i <f-1; i+=2)
    {
        n[i] = '.';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the [LiveDemo](http://ideone.com/tfy8Dc)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 bits of code causing errors:

1) Your first error occurs because you should be checking that `i < x.length()` in the first loop condition, not that `i <= x.length()` . Even better, calculate the length once and then use that value in the loop condition to avoid calling x.length() repeatedly. Your first loop should look like this:

```
int length = x.length();
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i)
```

note: ++i is quicker than i++ and in this case using ++i would not make a difference to the logic.

2) Your second error is due to the line `int f = x.length() * 2` because you are doubling the length of the array and then using that number to iterate through the array. For example, if your array has a length() of 5 then `int f = x.length() * 2` would mean that `f = 10` but if the length of the array is 5 than accessing the array with any number greater than 4 (array index starts at zero) would produce an error. In your second loop condition you do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < f-1; i+=2 ) {

    n[i] = '.' // i could easily be more than 4 at this point

}
```

To fix you second problem, take out the `* 2` from `int f = x.length() * 2`

3) Your third is because you haven't given the n string object a value yet you are accessing it using array indexing []

Comment: Calling x.length() is a constant time operation. I don't think pulling it out is worthwhile, and if it is, the compiler would probably do it for you.